# Show top 200 stores with highest shortage for last 3 years

Tags: powerbi, measure

I'm trying to create a measure to call out the top 200 stores for shortage for the last 3 years and top 200 for 2023.

I've created the measure below but it doesn't seem to work as the syntax is incorrect. What's wrong with my measure?

```
Top 200 L3Yrs = 
var L3Yrs = 
    FILTER(Append1, 
    YEAR(DATEVALUE(Append1[Year])) >= YEAR(TODAY()) -3
    && YEAR(DATEVALUE(Append1[Year])) <= YEAR(TODAY())
    )
Var TopStores = 
    TOPN(200,
    SUMMARIZE(L3Yrs, Append1[Store], "Total Shortage", [Total Shortage]), 
    [Total Shortage], DESC
    )
RETURN
TopStores
Top = 
VAR Yr2023 = 
  FILTER(Append1, YEAR(DATEVALUE(Append1[Year])) = 2023)
Var TopStores = 
    TOPN(200,
    SUMMARIZE(Yr2023, Append1[Store], "Total Shortage", [Total Shortage]), 
    [Total Shortage], DESC
    )
RETURN
    TopStores
```

Comment: Is that one measure or two measures?

Comment: its one measure

Comment: There are a few things wrong with the above.

 - An expression can only have one `RETURN`.
 - A Measure can only return a scalar value (ie not a table, or multiple values).
What is it you are wanting to do? Create a **Calculated Table** for each which will be static (not interacting with slicers), or create a visual?

Comment: I would like to create a measure or filter to callout/highlight stores that fit a certain criteria. Ideally it would find stores that have performed the worst over the last 3yrs in terms of cash over/short and the worst in 2023 and highlight them a certain color. Kind of a moving conditional formatting based off the given data